# Resistance to collision in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit

I have an app in which there are a number of medium to large size nodes endlessly bouncing around the screen.  Also, I have created a much tinier node whose purpose is to also bounce endlessly around the screen but when it encounters the larger nodes, those nodes should be strongly repelled,  while the tiny node should be minimally affected, if at all and stay on its previous trajectory.

What property do I set?  I have tried messing with mass and restitution to no avail.  How do I make it so that a much smaller object is significantly less affected by collisions than the larger nodes it is colliding with?

Note, that the app is working just fine, in that I have the collisions occurring as they should. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a sample of how you are setting mass for the small and large objects. Are you also setting an kind of restitution? What about damping?

Comment: give the tiny bodies an extreme amount of mass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set a really high density property

```
 node.physicsBody.density = 1000.0f
```

this should work

also you can increase elasticity of the larger ones so they bounce more

Comment: This works quite well.  One thing I have noticed however, is that the tiny node with the extreme density eventually slows down and stops, even with physicsWorld.gravity set to 0.0 and tinyNode.physicsBody.linearDampening set to 0.0.  That feels like unexpected behavior to me.

Comment: yes, when the body is moving it will lose speed. One thing you can do is set elasticity to a value more than 1 like 1.01 or something, therefore it will gain speed at every collision and is the only way that I can find to make the velocity seem constant

Comment: The best way (normally) that I am aware of to make the velocity constant is to set linear dampening to 0.  Without the tiny node causing collisions, the nodes will float around the screen indefinitely, without gaining or losing speed, and I attribute this to having set linear dampening to 0.0. Does that make sense?

Comment: I didn't know there was that property. thanks, and thats probably the answer